# VBA Advice needed

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have a requirement to hide a command button based on the user selecting an option button.
I have two Option buttons on my excel worksheet, One for 'Yes' and one for 'no'. If yes is selected then the command button that submits the worksheet to an email should be visible, if no is selected the command button should be invisible.
Here's what I have, but it's not working:

```
Sub OptionButton78_Click()
If Sheets("New Req").OptionButton78.Value = True Then
Sheets("New Req").CommandButton65.Enabled = True
Else
Sheets("New Req").CommandButton65.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

New Line of Code

```
Sub OptionButton78_Change()
    If OptionButton78 = True Then
        OptionButton79 = False
    Else
        OptionButton78 = True
    End If
End Sub

Sub Worksheet_Change()
     If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Req").Range("V1").Value = 2 Then
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Req").Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 2").Visible = False
          Else
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Req").Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 2").Visible = True
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button to disappear completely, use its visible property:

```
Sub OptionButton78_Click()
  If Sheets("New Req").OptionButton78.Value = True Then
    Sheets("New Req").CommandButton65.Visible = True
  Else
    Sheets("New Req").CommandButton65.Visible = False
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that too. I get the 'error 438', object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: I've now changed the command button to a shape. I can only get this working through the debugger. See code above. No error received now but just doesn't run on option button change.